# Run added job in APSchdule

Tags: python, apscheduler

I'm using APScheduler as BackgroundScheduler in my app.

main.py

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(change_store_status, trigger="interval", hours=23)
scheduler.start()
```

tasks.py

```
from main import scheduler
def create_schedule():
    scheduler.print_jobs()
    scheduler.add_job(hello, trigger="interval", seconds=2)
    scheduler.print_jobs()
```

Print like

```
Jobstore default:
     change_store_status (trigger: interval[23:00:00], next run at: 2016-05-17 14:53:07 ICT) 
Jobstore default:
     hello (trigger: interval[0:00:02], next run at: 2016-05-16 15:46:26 ICT)
     change_store_status (trigger: interval[23:00:00], next run at: 2016-05-17 14:53:07 ICT)
```

That mean job is added successfully but it not actual run. How to make it run. I tried add `scheduler.wakeup()` but it not work.

## P/S:

I found the problem is `APScheduler.BackgroundScheduler` thread. And running inside uWSGI make it failed. I tried enable uWSGI threads but it's still not working.

Comment: Have you tried any of the examples in the `examples` directory of the apscheduler tarball or source repository?

Comment: What do you mean ? If there is any example can solve it please give me a detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is APScheduler.BackgroundScheduler thread. And running inside uWSGI make it failed. I tried enable uWSGI threads but it's still not working.

Comment: This is not really an answer ... (how) did you solve it?

Comment: Do not use uWSGI outside this app